# IXmlSerializable Type 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement' must have default constructor

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

I am trying to get the data from my web service on monotouch(ios). I create a proxy class by using SlSvcUtil, I am trying to access a method from my proxy class like this

```
void OnGotResult(object sender, GetDataCompletedEventArgs  e)
{
    resultsLabel.Text = e.Result.ToString();
}
```

When I try to access `GetDataCompletedEventArgs` method in class geneerated from proxy class, it is throwing an exception with the message

> System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException:IXmlSerializable Type 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement' must have default constructor.
>
> Stack Trace of Exception :
>
> at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlDataContractInterpreter.GetConstructor () [0x00059] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2377/73229919/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/System.Runtime.Serialization/ReferenceSources/XmlDataContract_static.cs:49 
>     at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlDataContractInterpreter.CreateXmlSerializable () [0x00025] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2377/73229919/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/System.Runtime.Serialization/ReferenceSources/XmlDataContract_static.cs:34 
>     at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlDataContract.m__0 () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2377/73229919/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/external/referencesource/System.Runtime.Serialization/System/Runtime/Serialization/XmlDataContract.cs:14 
>     at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.ReadIXmlSerializable (System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlSerializableReader xmlSerializableReader, System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlDataContract xmlDataContract, Boolean isMemberType) [0x0008e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2377/73229919/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/external/referencesource/System.Runtime.Serialization/System/Runtime/Serialization/XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.cs:555 
>     at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.ReadIXmlSerializable (System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlDataContract xmlDataContract, Boolean isMemberType) [0x00016] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2377/73229919/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/external/referencesource/System.Runtime.Serialization/System/Runtime/Serialization/XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.cs:525 
>     at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlDataContract.ReadXmlValue (System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context) [0x00014] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2377/73229919/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/external/referencesource/System.Runtime.Serialization/System/Runtime/Serialization/XmlDataContract.cs:455

Help me solving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to make sure you're using a recent version of Xamarin.iOS. Xamarin.iOS 9.6.1.9 is fine. Xamarin.iOS 9.4 or 9.2 should work too.

Next you will need to tell the [managed linker](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/linker/) to preserve the default `System.Xml.Linq.XElement` constructor because that constructor is most likely only accessed via reflection in your current app. One way to preserve that type is to use a "[Custom Linker Configuration](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/custom_linking/)":

1. Create a new `Linker.xml` file in your iOS app project. (You can change the file name if you like.)
2. Add the following lines:

   ```
   <linker>
       <assembly fullname="System.Xml.Linq">
           <type fullname="System.Xml.Linq.XElement">
               <method name=".ctor" />
           </type>
       </assembly>
   </linker>
   ```
3. For each configuration (like "Debug|iPhone") that has the managed linker enabled, add the following text under *Project options > iOS Build > Additional mtouch arguments*:

   ```
   --xml=Linker.xml
   ```

Comment: Very good communication, helpful and quick support. I was able to find the right solution by the answer you provided..Thanks & Best Regards!